# How to copy an int array only with non leading zero

Tags: java, arrays

I have an int array which has few leading zeros. I want to copy this array into another int array without leading zeros.

this is the code I wrote. but this code copies only non zero ints.

Original array:

```
     int samples[]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33, 15, -32, 2030, 3223, 0, 0};
```

New array should be :

```
    int noleadingzeroarray[] = {40,0,2532, 17, -2300, -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33, 15, -32, 2030, 3223, 0, 0};
```

Code:

```
 public static void trimSilenceFromBeginning(){

    int leadingZeros = 0;
    int samples[]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33, 15, -32, 2030, 3223, 0, 0};
    int noleadingzeroarray[]= new int[samples.length];
    int zeroscounter= 0;
    boolean nonzeroencountered  = false;

    if(samples[leadingZeros] == 0) {
        leadingZeros++;

    }

    for(int j= 0; j< samples.length; j++){

        if(samples[j]!=0 ) {
                noleadingzeroarray[zeroscounter] = samples[j];
                zeroscounter++;               
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(noleadingzeroarray));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[**Arrays.copyOfRange**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) to just use `arrays` without other element involved (*Collections, etc*).

> *Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.
> The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and
> original.length, inclusive.*

3 lines:

```
int start;
for (start = 0; start < samples.length && samples[start] == 0; start++) {}
int[] noleadingzeroarray = Arrays.copyOfRange(samples, start, samples.length);
```

- If no zero is found in `samples`, **`start`** will be `0` - *the entire array will be shallow copied*
- If leading zeroes are found, **`start`** will be assigned the *starting index* after the last zero's position. - *a subarray will be shallow copied*

*Don't panic with the *shallow copy* term, they're ints (primitives). No problem.*

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void trimSilenceFromBeginning() {
    int samples[]= { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, 
                     -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33,
                     15, -32, 2030, 3223, 0, 0};

    int leadingZeros = 0;
    while (leadingZeros < samples.length && samples[leadingZeros] == 0) {
        leadingZeros++;
    }
    int[] noleadingzeroarray = Arrays.copyOfRange(samples, leadingZeroes, samples.length);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(noleadingzeroarray));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this using streams.  This will drop all values that are 0. Once a nonzero is detected, the rest of the arrays is streamed.

```
int[] samples = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, -17,
        -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33, 15, -32, 2030, 3223,
        0, 0 };


int[] result = Arrays.stream(samples)
        .dropWhile(a ->a == 0)
        .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Prints

```
[40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33, 15, -32, 2030, 322
3, 0, 0]
```

And here is a non stream solution using a while loop and range copy.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < samples.length) {
    if (samples[i] != 0) {
        samples = Arrays.copyOfRange(samples, i, samples.length);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: that is indeed a one liner : )

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention `dropWhile` is added in Java 9

Comment: We're already at Java 15.  I don't recall that when we were in Java 8, folks would mention that generics were added in Java 5.  It's about time folks caught up.

Answer (score 0):

change first if statement to

```
while(samples[leadingZeros] == 0) {
    leadingZeros++;

}
```

Comment: Good start but not all that needs to be done.

Comment: additionally the second if statement in the original code needs to be removed, and the for loop for copying should begin after the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

An example of applying Stream API to this task:

```java
int[] samples = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, 
                 -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33,
                 15, -32, 2030, 3223, 0, 0};

boolean[] nonZero = {false}; // or AtomicBoolean may be used instead

int[] noZeros = Arrays.stream(samples)
                      .filter(x -> nonZero[0] |= x != 0) // false until first non-0 detected
                      .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(noZeros));
```

Output:

```
[40, 0, 2532, 17, -2300, -17, -4000, 0, 2000, 1048, -420, 33, 15, -32, 2030, 3223, 0, 0]
```